# Easy way to get city from LocationManager on Android?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I'm trying to figure out the city of where the user is using their location. Using LocationManager and Geocoder I get some nice data from the longitude and latitude, but I can't get one thing. The subAdminArea a.k.a. the city. It always returns **null** for me, even though everything else including the postal code is received. Is there something I am missing?

Basically this is a method I call for getting data.

```
public String getLocation(Locale locale, Context context, boolean city, boolean postal, boolean state_prov) throws IOException{
    LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locList = new MyLocList();
    Geocoder gC = new Geocoder(context,locale);
    Location gpsLocation = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(locMan.GPS_PROVIDER);
    locMan.requestLocationUpdates(locMan.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500, 200, locList);
    Location networkLocation = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(locMan.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (city)
        return (gC.getFromLocation(networkLocation.getLatitude(), networkLocation.getLongitude(), 1).get(0).getSubAdminArea());
    else if (postal)
        return (gC.getFromLocation(networkLocation.getLatitude(), networkLocation.getLongitude(), 1).get(0).getPostalCode());
    else if (state_prov)
        return (gC.getFromLocation(networkLocation.getLatitude(), networkLocation.getLongitude(), 1).get(0).getAdminArea());
    else
        return "";
}
```

and the call to this method is done via:

```
String city = getLocation(Locale.getDefault(),getBaseContext(),true,false,false);
```

The only other option I have found through some research is sending a request to

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=POSTALCODE&sensor=true
```

and it gives me a JSON of that location based on the postal code, which I can then parse, but it seems like a lot of work to find the city.

Could there be something I am missing? Or something I did wrong? I am new to location services for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081733/1061177) and it worked perfectly fine. It was able to get the location despite the problems I initially had in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < addresses.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
 Log.d("=Adress=",addresses.getAddressLine(i));
}
```

You will get postal code, city , country, ....

Comment: It seems as though changing my location to another area got a city reading. This is weird. But this still returns null for the subAdminArea at home. Not sure what's causing this.